# Text in paragraph tag getting cut off

Tags: html, css

Here is the [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/xpqq7j76/)

I have created an ebay template. The problem that I am facing is that the text in the paragraph text in the middleContent tag is getting hidden. I want the text to show properly.

Help is much appreciated.

```
.middleTheme p {
    padding: 0 5px;
    margin: 0;
    float: none;
}
```

Comment: rearange this <div class"middlecontent"=""> to <div class="middlecontent"> in your code

Answer (score 1):

Your markup is a little bit hard to look at, but I'm guessing that you definitely have unclosed elements in your markup.

Try replacing:

```
<div class"middleContent">
<p>The sentence starts here</p>
```

with:

```
<div class="middleContent">
<p>The sentence starts here</p>
</div>
```

If you validate your markup at http://validator.w3.org/unicorn/ you will easily be able to fix this kind of error.